# How to toggle selection state of a selected (focused) item with TListView with disabled MultiSelect?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tlistview

I have a `TListView` with `MultiSelect` set to `False`.

I want to toggle selection state of a currently selected item. I mean, unselect item which is currently selected (focused). But allow switching selection (focus) to another item. The same toggle you can see when having `MultiSelect` enabled and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on a selected item.

I have tried the `OnChanging` event, but got lost completely because of the re-entrance to the method.

I finally made a very ugly workaround with the `OnEditing` event e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.CMUnselectItems(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(Item) then
  begin
    ListView1.Selected := nil;
    ListView1.ItemFocused := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Editing(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  var AllowEdit: Boolean);
begin
  AllowEdit := False;
  PostMessage(Self.Handle, CM_UnselectItems, 0, 0);
end;
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Maybe waiting in the `WM_NOTIFY` message for the `NM_CLICK` notification, in the `NMITEMACTIVATE` structure check and modify the `uNewState` member (`LVIS_FOCUSED` and `LVIS_SELECTED` flags). The question is if this notification is sent even when the user clicks on the same item after a "long time" (when no change actually occurs). Cannot verify now.

Comment: @Victoria, `NM_CLICK` does not provide valid `uNewState`/`uOldState`. it is sent each time the user clicks an item. however no special information there. seems like the only way is `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` but I can't figure out how to deal with it. there might be a timer involved which triggers this notification twice if item already selected (I'm not sure).

Comment: Have you properly masked the flags (in these messages always inspect states). If so, then you can still perform `LVM_GETITEMSTATE` and `LVM_SETITEMSTATE`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23570100

Comment: I haven't suggested `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` notification because it's sent for an item that is being selected so as for item that is being unselected.